# IPython notebook does not produce output

Tags: ipython, windows-7-x64, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have just installed IPython 2.0 (April 2014) through Anaconda (64 bit) on a brand new pc with windows 7 (64 bit), performed the updates suggested and installed some packages with "$ conda install ".

I am loading IPython notebook with firefox and chrome. they are not the default browsers, so I used the information in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15748692/2344958

When I run IPython Notebook, it presents the landing pages and open new or imported notebooks, but it does not produce any output for cells. 
I have no clue. 
The only thing I can see is that the web console reports "Empty string passed to getElementById()."

Console works fine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a page describing exactly the problem I had.
here the page:
[Getting output with IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036197/ipython-notebook-getting-output)

I actually have Sophos, but I have no control over it, and the solution that works so far was to start IPython with:

```
ipython notebook --ip=localhost
```

It also works by editing the line in configuration file
   c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'

Comment: Was having a similar issue on Linux 16.04 LTS, this fixed it.