# Ipython notebook does not execute anything

Tags: python, ipython

I am a newbie in python. I am using python 2.7 version. I installed ipython notebook (version 4.0.0). when I use command "ipython notebook", I get the webpage fine.

However,when I create a new notebook and try to execute something ( very simple things like `print "hello world"` or `1+1` , nothing happens. The code does not even appear in different colours. It just shows In[*] as I press ctrl+enter or click upon the run button.

Also, I have referred to a similar question here: [IPython notebook does not produce output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864575/ipython-notebook-does-not-produce-output)

I tried using ip=localhost, also tried disabling the antivirus and firewall before executing as given in the previous answer, but still no luck. I already re installed python hoping to get rid of this issue.

My OS is Windows 7 and my browser is Mozilla Firefox 41.0.2

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the kernel by selecting Kernel > Restart in the toolbar.